# How can I view progress of git gc in the background?

Tags: git

When I run a command like `git gc`, I get a message like this:

```
$ git fetch
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
```

It seems like newer versions of Git run auto-packing in the background now, which is a nice feature! If I run `git gc` manually, I get this message:

```
$ git gc
fatal: gc is already running on machine 'machinename' pid 14009 (use --force if not)
```

This makes sense. However, I would quite like to be able to watch the progress of `gc` that is running the background somehow?

Obviously, I could run something like `while ! git gc ; do sleep 1s ; done`, but that doesn't give me nearly as much information as a pretty Git progress indicator could, and it runs auto-packing an additional time.

Comment: Try sending `SIGUSR1` with the `watch` command.

Comment: @hjpotter92 That doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure it to be non-background, then I belive it should report its progress:

```
 git config gc.autoDetach false
```

Comment: This doesn't actually do anything to an already running background gc, it simply prevents any future command from doing the gc in the background.