# How to tell if git gc is currently running?

Tags: git, garbage-collection

I want to check the files in a bare git repo (i.e. the files that are normally in .git) but only if garbage collection is not in progress. I've tried checking for gc.pid but that seems to be left behind after gc has finished, so doesn't reliably show whether gc is still in progress.

Answer (score 0):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39600398/6309), it seems a `git gc` done while one is currently running would trigger

```
fatal: gc is already running on machine 'machinename' pid xxx
```

But in your case, disabling `git gc` in the background (as [I explained before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32025729/6309)) might be an option.